# Handling String passed into JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json, pubnub

In my PHP server I am passing what should be an encoded JSONObject into the PubNub channel as:

```
$post_data = array("type"=> "groupMessage", "data" => array("chatUser" => "SERVER", "chatMsg" => "Now lets talk", "chatTime"=>1446514201516));
$post_data = json_encode($post_data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
$info = $pubnub->publish('MainChat', $post_data);
```

Note that I am using `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`, which should ensure output of JSONObject. Referencing the logs, the output appears as:

```
{"type":"groupMessage","data":{"chatUser":"SERVER","chatMsg":"Now lets talk","chatTime":1446514201516}}
```

However, within the client Android app, testing the class of the incoming message on the channel returns that this is a String object, not JSON, and does not get passed `if (message instanceof JSONObject) {`:

```
            Log.d("message class", message.getClass().toString());

            if (message instanceof JSONObject) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) message;
                    Log.d("jsonObj is ", jsonObj.toString());

                    JSONObject json = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
                    final String name = json.getString(Constants.JSON_USER);
                    Log.d("name is: ", name);
                    final String msg = json.getString(Constants.JSON_MSG);
                    Log.d("msg is: ", msg);
                    final long time = json.getLong(Constants.JSON_TIME);
                    Log.d("time is: ", String.valueOf(time) );
                    if (name.equals(mPubNub.getUUID())) return; // Ignore own messages
                    final ChatMessage chatMsg = new ChatMessage(name, msg, time);
                    presentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Adding messages published to the channel
                            mChatAdapter.addMessage(chatMsg);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

How can I ensure that PHP passes a JSONObject into the channel?

Comment: The response (message) on the device is still just a string. You need to convert it to JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(message) to make it an instance of a JSONObject

Comment: @Sauron - isn't this just a duplicate question you asked here  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490282/pubnub-server-does-not-format-message-properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response (message) that you get on your device is still just a string which needs to be converted to a JSONObject().

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(message);
```

Now it can be checkd if it's a proper instance of a JSONObject() ;)